# Can't connect to MySQL server on (ip or domain name)

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I'm trying to configure a web server (Debian 7). I followed this [tutorial](http://olange.developpez.com/articles/debian/installation-serveur-dedie/?page=page_2).
I'm renting my server thanks to gandi.net service. And i have now apache2, mysql, php5 up and running.
I connect to it using following command on terminal : `ssh username@domainname.com`

Next step is to create my database through sequel pro and I don't know how to do it and documentation is not so clear...
Here is what I'm talking about :
[image]

I have tried to connect :

- Nom : some name, i found clear. (I think i can put anything in here, right ?)
- Host : ip or domain name
- User : the username I'm using in my ssh connection (cf above)
- Password : the password I both use for ssh connection (cf above) and mysql connection

For the rest, I left like it was and I received this error message :

> Unable to connect to host domainname.com, or the request timed out.
>
> Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).
>
> MySQL said:  Can't connect to MySQL server on 'domainename.com' (61)' (2)

Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you do a normal install of MySQL on Debian, it will be configured to block external connections to the database.

This means that you still need to tell MySQL that external access is OK. To do this, you need to update the bind address for MySQL. This is configured in `my.cnf`, which, on Debian based systems, is located in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

In there, find the section that says

```
[mysqld]
```

In there, you must make sure that

- the line `skip-networking` is either commented (comments start with a '#') or not there, and
- Bind-address is set to either `0.0.0.0` (which it is if there is no line bind-address) or to your server's IP-address.

After doing this, you should restart your MySQL service. Then you need to create a user that is allowed remote access. This can be done with a SQL query:

```
GRANT ALL ON yourdatabase.* TO youruser@'*' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
```

You can switch out the asterisk for the IP-address you will connect from, if it's the same every time.

Finally , you need to open port 3306 (the port MySQL uses) on your firewall. This usually isn't neccesary as it is already open on most systems, but it can be done using the following iptables command.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

Source: [1](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: please make your answer self contained so it works when linked sites go down.

Comment: @1010 did an attempt in this way. Does this format work?

Comment: In case it matters, the relevant config file on a recent raspbian was found to be `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`.

Answer (score 9):

This is the solution that worked for me: In Debian 7 look in the my.cnf under /etc/mysql/my.cnf and find the following lines:

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

Now change the `127.0.0.1` to the IP address of the mysql server, you want to connect or `0.0.0.0` for no restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find .cnf file hence I did the following:

```
sudo find / -name "*.cnf"

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

I edited **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** based on

```
strace mysql ";" 2>&1  | grep cnf

stat("/etc/my.cnf", 0x7ffda9472660)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=683, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", O_RDONLY)     = 3
stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
stat("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3034, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
stat("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=21, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
stat("/root/.my.cnf", 0x7ffda9472660)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/root/.mylogin.cnf", 0x7ffda9472660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And changed **bind-address** to my local IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
>
> set localhost in the file httpd.conf as follows
>
> ServerName localhost
>
> or else the port won't accept your server request, and will show cant
>   connect to server ip_address

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue by simply running this line on terminal

```
ALTER USER 'your_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';
```

`your_user = root` for me
`your_password = something` choose what ever you want

Answer (score 0):

1. `locate my.cnf`
2. vi < copy the path >
   for e.g. ==> `vi /usr/local/etc/my.cnf`
3. Now you see and compare below if you find difference then update

> ```
> # Default Homebrew MySQL server config  
> [mysqld]
> # Only allow connections from localhost  
> bind-address = 0.0.0.0
> ```

Now press button =>  esc and :wq    (vi commands)

Restart the MySQL =>

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Now good to go...

Answer (score 0):

if all ways not worked probebly its from nftables
stop that bu this command and try again
`sudo systemctl stop nftables`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).