# Cannot Connect to Port 3306 MySql Server on Centos from Windows

Tags: mysql, tcp, dbvisualizer

I am trying to play around with MySql on a CentOs7 Server, mostly by ssh on a Windows machine. I cannot seem to connect on to port 3306 from DBVisualizer which I am running on the Windows side.
I receive the following error in the DBVisualizer GUI:

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Details:
   Type: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
   SQL State: 08S01
```

I have no problem sshing through port 22. There are a number of posts on this matter including these and others from UnixStack:

[Can't connect to MySQL server on (ip or domain name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221220/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-ip-or-domain-name)

[com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121829/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexceptioncommunications-link-fail)

I have taken a look at each and tried to implement them but nothing seems to be working. I have reconfigured the iptables a number of times. I have run nmap on the ports with this output.

```
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
3306/tcp open  mysql
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
```

The second post did suggest that it could be JDBC issues, but I am not exactly sure how to check that, especially since I am trying to connect through an IDE.

Comment: did you check firewall rules?

Comment: @vladkras that's what the IPTables are showing you

Comment: i stopped firewalld with systemctl

Comment: @djthoms my bad, I thought it was `netstat`, @JackFrye can you connect with `telnet`?

Comment: that's what I am not sure about. I would think dbvisualizer would use tcp. Isnt that what is used to do remote connections to mysqldb?

Comment: no it timed out

Comment: Can you connect using the `mysql` commands from your localhost? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

Comment: so it's not a driver issue but network one

Comment: i would assume i would need to install mysql locally? would it use the same binaries on windows/be able to communicate?

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985169/1713660

Comment: yeah, answer is quoted from my second source